# How can I deconstruct a Spray API HTTPResponse?

Tags: scala, solr, akka, spray

I'm using Spray API (spray-client) to hit an internal Solr URL, I want to be able to parse the response into a Scala case class.

If I just expect and HTTPResponse, I'm getting a value back, but when I try to marshal it into my case class, it fails (I can't produce a message other than null(), because I'm using matching and obviously not getting the right test case.)

I think some of my problem is that it's returning the data in the form of `text/plain` instead of `application/json`. When I expect HttpResponse instead of my case class,

```
val f: Future[HttpResponse] =
    (IO(Http) ? Get("http://1.2.3.4:8983/solr/collection1/select?q=*%3A*&wt=json")).mapTo[HttpResponse]
```

I get:

```
HttpResponse(200 OK,HttpEntity(text/plain; charset=UTF-8,
{
  "responseHeader":{"status":0,"QTime":65,"params":{"q":"*:*","wt":"json"}},
  "response":{"numFound":147437873,"start":0,"maxScore":1.0,"docs":
    [
      {"guid":"TLQ0jVlMYCXQrYkBIZHNXfMmifw+3","alias":["greg"],"_version_":1440942010264453120},
      {"guid":"TQsDY1ZG7q+Ne5e6F7qAUhFyomSH9","_version_":1440942010296958976},
      {"guid":"TzWB5grOBAJJZcAQDo2k9xBUVGPFr","alias":["spark"],"_version_":1440942010298007552},
      {"guid":"T0judCG4UI9RYqDDQVcn+gyZEU7Bb","alias":["zombie"],...),List(Connection: close, Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8),HTTP/1.1)
```

But when I change that to expect my case class, I can't match. So, how can I marshal the data it returns into a Scala case class? Here's what I have tried:

```
case class SolrParams(q: String, wt: String)
case class SolrResponseHeader(status: String, qtime: String, params: SolrParams)
case class SolrDoc(guid: String, alias: List[String], version: String)
case class SolrResponse(numFound: Long, start: Long, maxScore: String, docs: List[SolrDoc])

case class SolrApResult(responseHeader: SolrResponseHeader, response: SolrResponse)

object SolrJsonProtocol extends DefaultJsonProtocol {
  implicit val paramsFormat = jsonFormat2(SolrParams)
  implicit val responseHeaderFormat = jsonFormat2(SolrResponseHeader)
  implicit val docFormat = jsonFormat3(SolrDoc)
  implicit val responseFormat = jsonFormat4(SolrResponse)
  implicit def solrApiResultFormat = jsonFormat2(SolrApiFullResult)
}

...

val f: Future[SolrApiResult] =
    (IO(Http) ? Get("http://1.2.3.4:8983/solr/collection1/select?q=*%3A*&wt=json")).mapTo[SolrApiResult]
```

Which gives me no match in an `f onComplete ...` structure. Could the issue be that my case classes aren't matching what's being returned, and if so, what suggestions do you have to troubleshoot it better?

I've been [all over the docs](http://spray.io/documentation/1.2-M8/) and they're either incomplete or a bit dated, plus I'm new at this game so that's not helping either.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The main issue I see with your code is that you are expecting `mapTo` to automatically unmarshall the http response body into your case class structure.  The `mapTo` method belongs to the `Future` class and has no idea about json unmarshalling.  You use `mapTo` within an Akka request (which `?` is doing under the hood) to basically "cast" a `Future[Any]` (which is the default response type from `?`) into the type that will actually be returned.  This has nothing to do with json unmarshalling.  I believe in order to achieve what you want, you should create a `pipeline` for spray that will both send the request and unmarshall the response.  The documentation showing examples of that are [here](http://spray.io/documentation/1.1.2/spray-client/).  I think for your example, it would look something like this (code may not be 100% right, just trying to show general flow):

```
val pipeline = sendReceive ~> unmarshall[SolrApiResult]
val response:Future[SolrApiResult] = pipeline(Get("http://1.2.3.4:8983/solr/collection1/select?q=*%3A*&wt=json"))
```

Comment: Ok that's good to know--I did think `.mapTo` had extra magic that it apparently does not. Thank you

Comment: @cmbaxter, the linked `here` does not exist now.